# Tensorflow - How to handle sequence input data (Sequence Data Input Layer)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a bunch of time series.
The data is in the following format:

```py
input_data = {
    'category_a': tf.Variable([[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
                                3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5,
                                6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9],
                               [5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 9, 9, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=tf.int32),
    'numeric_a': tf.Variable([[0.23378488, 0.20349434, 0.20352034, 0.20349434, 0.23378488,
                               0.20352034, 0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.23378488, 0.20352034,
                               0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.23378488, 0.20352034, 0.20349434,
                               0.20349434, 0.23378488, 0.20352034, 0.20349434, 0.20349434,
                               0.23378488, 0.20352034, 0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.23378488,
                               0.20349434, 0.20352034, 0.20349434, 0.20719424, 0.2086331 ,
                               0.23439065, 0.20352887, 0.23439065, 0.20352887, 0.2086331 ,
                               0.20719424, 0.23439065, 0.20352887, 0.2086331 , 0.20719424,
                               0.20352066, 0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.20352066, 0.23267019,
                               0.2035374 , 0.24012332, 0.21045385, 0.24012332, 0.21045385,
                               0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.20349434],
                              [0.20351858, 0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.20351858, 0.23157308,
                               0.23044993, 0.2035374 , 0.20349434, 0.20349434, 0.20349434,
                               0.20349434, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
                               0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]], dtype=tf.float32)
}
```

The 'category a' represents a categorical variable, which I'd like to one-hot encode (as with the [feature_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns) indicator column).
Split tensors per feature. The first dimension represents the batch size (2). The second dimension the timesteps with a sequence length (53). All sequences are padded to the max sequence length per batch size. Max sequence length can differ per batch.

So the values in the tensor are the value of a feature at a given timestep for that specific time series.

**How can I get this data fed into a model like an lstm?**

I looked at the tensorflow [feature_columns](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns), which work with data in a similar format.
They have been pretty helpful for encoding categorical data (e.g. the indicator_column and categorical_column)

I looked at `keras.experimental.SequenceFeatures`, it seems to offer the required functionality, but I couldn't get it to work, and working code snippets for it were hard for me to find.

I'm indifferent to whether the implementation is in Keras or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Keras LSTM can handle your input without needing to store it in a tensorflow variable. However for your case you would need to reformat the data so that the batch size is the 1st dimension, 2nd is the timesteps and 3rd is the features.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(number_of_neurons, 
               activation=activation_function,
               return_sequences=False, 
               input_shape=(number_of_timesteps, number_of_features)))
```

The `input_shape` option is used to define the shape of your data.

At the end of your model you can then provide the data and targets separately in `training_data` and  `training_target`

```
model.fit(training_data, 
          training_target,
          batch_size=batch, 
          epochs=epoch,
          validation_data=(test_data, test_target))
```

Which in your case would be:

```
[[[3.0, 0.23378488], [3.0, 0.20349434], ...]
  [5.0, 0.20351858], [5.0, 0.20349434], ...]
   ...]]]
```

The **Stacked LSTM for sequence classification** example in the keras documentation is a good starting point:
https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/#examples

Comment: Many thanks for the help, but the first feature is a categorical variable. I edited the question for that missing clarification.

Comment: In that case you could always one-hot encode the variable and have one feature per category. Just store a 1 in the category of that timestep and 0 in the rest